# The integration of an exponential function

Tags: probability

The problem is solving the integration of $e^{-L(x-a)^2}$ for $x$, to get the answer $(\pi/L)^{1/2}$.

Please make the steps obvious for me to understand, and point me to some resources for me to improve in the field if you can.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2} \, dx = \sqrt{2\pi} \tag 1
$$
has probably been the topic of various questions posted here.

You have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-L(x-a)^2} \, dx.
$$
Let $u = \sqrt{2L}(x-a)$, so that $du = \sqrt{2L}\,dx$ and $dx=\dfrac{du}{\sqrt{2L}}$.  Then your integral becomes
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2/2} \, \frac{du}{\sqrt{2L}}.
$$
By $(1)$, this is
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{2L}} = \sqrt{\frac \pi L}.
$$

This is **not** about "solving for $x$".  It is about evaluating the integral.

Comment: sir i understand the solution that you have given ,but as a student it might confuse me a little bit because if i have x^2 instead of (x-a)^2 i will have the same answer so the integral seams to be not effected by the symbol a .what does that mean ??and thank you so much you've bean really helpful  .

Comment: @مريمابوعرة : Say you have $\displaystyle \int_{\text{something}}^{\text{something}} g(x-a)\,dx$.  Let $u=x-a$ so that $du=dx$.  Then the integral becomes $\displaystyle\int_{\text{something}-a}^{\text{something}-a} g(u)\,du$.  However, as $\text{something} \to +\infty$ then $(\text{something}-a)\to+\infty$ and as $\text{something} \to -\infty$ then $(\text{something}-a)\to-\infty$, so you get $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(u)\,du$, and that is the same as $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(x)\, dx$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: i am starting my third year as a physicist student and i want to improve my self in math specially integrals differential equation and partial diff. equ ,so do you suggest a book ?

Comment: I don't have a specific book in mind, but whatever ability I have in matters of this kind came from doing lots of exercises, so maybe you should look for those. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the proof at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral? It goes through a couple of proofs for a particular form of that integral, and you can prove the more general form through a change of variable.